# Qt application doesn't block when run from command-line

Tags: qt, cmd

If I run a Qt application directly from the Windows command-line (`cmd`), it immediately returns back to the shell even as the GUI continues running; I assume it creates a second process before the parent exits.

[image: Qt application running while the terminal is at a new shell prompt]

If I run the Qt application indirectly though, from a batch file or Python script, it doesn't behave the same way; it blocks until the application actually exits:

[image: Qt application running while the terminal blocks]

Is this standard Qt behavior? I can't find any mention of it in the documentation or anywhere else. Can it be customized? I would prefer that the application always block when run from the command-line.

Comment: I guess it has to do with the context of console output. The fix should be specific to process launch and not Qt.

Comment: Why do you want running the application to block at an interactive prompt? Does it attach to its parent's console via `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)`? Otherwise the only reason I can see for this is to set the exit code in `%errorlevel%`. The default behavior is there because it makes no sense in most cases to have CMD wait around for a GUI app or a console app that creates a new console via `start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NORMAL Windows behavior.

In a console console programs are waited on. GUI programs are not. The rules are specified in `start /?`(mention of new behavior is NT4 to Windows 2000).

So `Start /w c:\windows\notepad`.

Comment: Ah, you're right; I kept searching for Qt specifically and that was making it hard to find. Turns out this is already discussed on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/908664/have-the-command-prompt-launch-an-application-like-notepad-and-block-until-it-is)